# Boost.Any vs. Boost.Variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, boost-any

I'm having trouble choosing between Boost.Any and Boost.Variant.
When should I use each one?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

I am basically looking to store some states from external sources.

Comment: If you know all the possible types that data can have at compile time, then use Boost.Variant: the number of types that your data can have is finite and types are verified at compilation. If those types can be anything, then use Boost.Any.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have you looked at the [comparison](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any) in the variant library already?

(Not sure what states from external sources are, so it's kind of hard to say what's more appropriate for you.)

Comment: Actually I haven't seen that before.
But what is the right question to ask to help me choose?

Comment: You would have to answer that yourself - which of the features is critical for you?

Comment: Ease of use, no maintainability headaches, the least overhead possible. I can estimate what my types are going to be but what if I need to add yet another one tomorrow?

Comment: @Hackingwords: Assume it's some kind of Driver.