# How to store different data types in one list? (C++)

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need to store a list of various properties of an object. Property consists of a name and data, which can be of any datatype.

I know I can make a class "Property", and extend it with different PropertySubClasses which only differ with the datatype they are storing, but it does not feel right.

```
class Property
{
     Property(std::string name);
     virtual ~Property();

     std::string m_name;
};

class PropertyBoolean : Property
{
     PropertyBoolean(std::string name, bool data);

     bool m_data;
};

class PropertyFloat : Property
{
     PropertyFloat(std::string name, float data);

     float m_data;
};

class PropertyVector : Property
{
     PropertyVector(std::string name, std::vector<float> data);

     std::vector<float> m_data;
};
```

Now I can store all kinds of properties in a

```
 std::vector<Property*>
```

and to get the data, I can cast the object to the subclass. Or I can make a pure virtual function to do something with the data inside the function without the need of casting.

Anyways, this does not feel right to create these different kind of subclasses which only differ by the data type they are storing. Is there any other convenient way to achieve similar behavior?

I do not have access to Boost.

Comment: Similar to what you want using Boost.Variant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358427/function-which-returns-an-unknown-type

Comment: Your `PropertyXxxx` classes need to inherit from `class Property`.  You may want to edit your post.

Comment: Seems that templates is the way to go. Have you considered them ?

Comment: Can you explain why boost is not an option? If it really isn't, and your list of types is small, use either subclassing, or a discriminated union. If the number of property types are large, you can make your own 'any' type.

Comment: I think you want to inherit with `: public Property` (which expresses an "is-a" relationship) rather than `: Property` (which uses default, private inheritance and expresses a "has-a" relationship). Or is my C++ really rusty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you make a heterogeneous boost::map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251403/how-do-you-make-a-heterogeneous-boostmap)

Comment: Same problem as "how do you make a heterogeneous boost::map?" just swap list for map. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559412/how-to-store-different-data-types-in-one-list-c

Comment: If boost is not an option, then implement your own `variant` / `any`. The latter should use inheritance under the hood, but the polymorphism is hidden away from the user giving the object normal value semantics. And it has a smart "cast" function of its own to determine the stored type.

Comment: Whenever you're repeating something, and just changing types, use a template. Also, if Boost is not an option you're best bet is to basically re-implement the bare requirements based off Boost.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

C++ is a multi-paradigm language. It shines brightest and is most powerful where paradigms are mixed.

```
class Property
{
public:
    Property(const std::string& name) //note: we don't lightly copy strings in C++
      : m_name(name) {}
    virtual ~Property() {}
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

template< typename T >
class TypedProperty : public Property
{
public:
    TypedProperty (const std::string& name, const T& data)
      : Property(name), m_data(data);
private:
    T m_data;
};

typedef std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Property> > property_list_type;
```

---

***Edit:*** Why using `std::shared_ptr<Property>` instead of `Property*`?
Consider this code:

```
void f()
{
  std::vector<Property*> my_property_list;
  for(unsigned int u=0; u<10; ++u)
    my_property_list.push_back(new Property(u));

  use_property_list(my_property_list);

  for(std::vector<Property*>::iterator it=my_property_list.begin();
                                      it!=my_property_list.end(); ++it)
    delete *it;
}
```

That `for` loop there attempts to cleanup, deleting all the properties in the vector, just before it goes out of scope and takes all the pointers with it.
Now, while this might seem fine for a novice, if you're an only mildly experienced C++ developer, that code should raise alarm bells as soon as you look at it.

The problem is that the call to `use_property_list()` might throw an exception. If so, the function `f()` will be left right away. In order to properly cleanup, the destructors for all automatic objects created in `f()` will be called. That is, `my_property_list` will be properly destroyed. `std::vector`'s destructor will then nicely cleanup the data it holds. *However, it holds **pointers***, and how should `std::vector` know whether these pointers are the last ones referencing their objects?
Since it doesn't know, it won't delete the objects, it will only destroy the pointers when it destroys its content, leaving you with objects on the heap that you don't have any pointers to anymore. This is what's called a "leak".

In order to avoid that, you would need to catch all exceptions, clean up the properties, and the rethrow the exception. But then, ten years from now, someone has to add a new feature to the 10MLoC application this has grown to, and, being in a hurry, adds code which leaves that function prematurely when some condition holds. The code is tested and it works and doesn't crash - only the server it's part of now leaks a few bytes an hour, making it crash due to being out of memory about once a week. Finding that makes for many hours of *fine* debugging.

Bottom line: Never manage resources manually, always wrap them in objects of a class designed to handle exactly one instance of such a resource. For dynamically allocated objects, those handles are called *"smart pointer"*, and the most used one is `shared_ptr`.

Comment: But `std::shared_ptr` isn't part of C++ yet. And if he isn't allowed to use Boost, he most likely won't be allowed to use the TR1 extensions nor C++0x either.

Comment: @phlipsy: Oh, I simply overlooked the statement about boost. That's dumb. Anyway, if a shop doesn't allow boost, they'll have to have their own smart pointer anyway - [as bad as this usually is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437053/boost-advocacy-help-needed/1437748#1437748), it's still better than having no smart pointer. Also, some compilers already support `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: What's the point of shared_ptr here compared to regular pointer?

Comment: @hasdf: `std::shared_ptr` is a "smart pointer". It allows an arbitrary number of `std::shared_ptr` instances to share the same objects, but will automatically delete the object when the last `std::shared_ptr` instance referring to dies.

Comment: Well, can't I just easily use "delete" to delete the object?

Comment: @hasdf: It's not the question whether you _can_, but whether you _have to_. I'll add an explanation to my answer, since this would be too long for a comment.

Comment: Clear answer. But, what if exceptions are not used at all? Then this is not a problem.

Comment: @hasdf: You should read __all__ of my treatise. That's why I wrote it. (Add to that that the std lib sometimes throws exceptions. You do use the std lib, don't you?)

Comment: This looks solid and all, but there's still one thing -- How do we retrieve m_data from the list?

Comment: @MGZero: In OOP you wouldn't want to get at `m_data`, because it's an internal to `TypedProperty<T>`. The common way to work with that data is to have a pure virtual function in `Property` which does whatever you want to do and which is overridden in the template derived from it. Then, [instead of getting your hands on the property's private parts in order to do what you want to do, you invoke the virtual function which does it](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf).

Comment: @sbi As virtual templated member functions are not possible, how do you go about creating this pure virtual function? Do you have to implement a separate pure virtual function for every type supported?

Comment: @Steve: Please read the article I linked to in the above comment. Then ask: What is `Property` there for? What are you supposed to do with it? If you're doing OO, rather than getting at its innards to do that yourself, you tell it to do it by calling a (virtual) member function. (If that doesn't help, you need to describe your problem, and what you want to do with `Property`. That's probably best done in its own question. Feel free to link to it in a comment response here, although I rarely answer questions nowadays.)

Comment: I have a question. In the loop you write `new Property( u )` but I do not see an appropriate `Property` constructor. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 12):

A lower-level way is to use a union

```
class Property
  union {
    int int_data;
    bool bool_data;
    std::cstring* string_data;
  };
  enum { INT_PROP, BOOL_PROP, STRING_PROP } data_type;
  // ... more smarts ...
};
```

Dunno why your other solution doesn't feel right, so I don't know if this way would feel better to you.

EDIT: Some more code to give an example of usage.

```
Property car = collection_of_properties.head();
if (car.data_type == Property::INT_PROP) {
  printf("The integer property is %d\n", car.int_data);
} // etc.
```

I'd probably put that sort of logic into a method of the class where possible. You'd also have members such as this constructor to keep the data and type field in sync:

```
Property::Property(bool value) {
  bool_data = value;
  data_type = BOOL_PROP;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? I do not understand this

Comment: @hasdf: The union lets you store any of the constituent types, but only one at a time (basically all the members share the same region of memory). And then it's up to you to use the `data_type` field to keep track of what type is actually stored.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest `boost::variant` or `boost::any`. [[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366524/boost-any-vs-boost-variant)]

Answer (score 2):

Write a template class `Property<T>` that derives from `Property` with a data member of type `T`

Comment: You still wouldn't be able to put them into an array or an stl container.  Property<int> and Property<float> are entirely different types.

Comment: @Dima: Yes, but in the example they are stored by pointer anyway.

Comment: @Dima: Not if they have a common superclass, which I think is what jdv meant by "derives from `Property`".

Comment: Right, you could have a collection of pointers to the base class.  But then there is still a problem: to get the value of the property, you need to know which subclass it is.

Comment: @Dima: You can dynamic cast to find out. Usually you know which types you put in, so that's what you will be looking for. And in this case the properties have text labels. So he'll probable use a Date type to store the "Birthday" property.

Comment: Incomplete answer. To make this work properly (with erase/sort support) for any container you'll need smart pointers. Plus OP already did that...

Comment: @jdv: I know, but this still feels wrong.  Usually when you have to ask an object what class it is, that is an indication of a design flaw.

Comment: This works very well so long as a common interface to your properties, like conversion to and from a string.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with C++ 17 we have something called as `std::variant` and `std::any`.

**std::variant**

An instance of `std::variant` at any given time either holds a value of one of its alternative types, or in the case of error - no value.

**std::any**

The class any describes a type-safe container for single values of any copy constructible type.

1. An object of class any stores an instance of any type that satisfies the constructor requirements or is empty, and this is referred to as the state of the class any object. The stored instance is called the contained object. Two states are equivalent if they are either both empty or if both are not empty and if the contained objects are equivalent.
2. The non-member any_cast functions provide type-safe access to the contained object.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to write a intermediate class managing the pointers to `Property` classes:

```
class Bla {
private:
  Property* mp
public:
  explicit Bla(Property* p) : mp(p) { }

  ~Bla() { delete p; }

  // The standard copy constructor
  // and assignment operator
  // aren't sufficient in this case:
  // They would only copy the 
  // pointer mp (shallow copy)
  Bla(const Bla* b) : mp(b.mp->clone()) { }

  Bla& operator = (Bla b) { // copy'n'swap trick
    swap(b);
    return *this;
  }

  void swap(Bla& b) {
    using std::swap; // #include <algorithm>
    swap(mp, b.mp);
  }

  Property* operator -> () const {
    return mp;
  }

  Property& operator * () const {
    return *mp;
  }
};
```

You have to add a virtual `clone` method to your classes returning a pointer to a newly created copy of itself:

```
class StringProperty : public Property {
// ...
public:
  // ...
  virtual Property* clone() { return new StringProperty(*this); }
  // ...
};
```

Then you'll be able to do this:

```
std::vector<Bla> v;
v.push_back(Bla(new StringProperty("Name", "Jon Doe")));
// ...
std::vector<Bla>::const_iterator i = v.begin();
(*i)->some_virtual_method();
```

Leaving the scope of `v` means that all `Bla`s will be destroyed freeing automatically the pointers they're holding. Due to its overloaded dereferencing and indirection operator the class `Bla` behaves like an ordinary pointer. In the last line `*i` returns a reference to a `Bla` object and using `->` means the same as if it was a pointer to a `Property` object.

A possible drawback of this approach is that you always get a heap operation (a `new` and a `delete`) if the intermediate objects must be copied around. This happens for example if you exceed the vector's capacity and all intermediate objects must be copied to a new piece of memory.

In the new standard (i.e. c++0x) you'll be able to use the `unique_ptr` template: It

- can be used inside the standard containers (in contrast to the `auto_ptr` which must not be used in the standard containers),
- offers the usually faster move semantics (it can easily passed around) and
- takes care over the held pointers (it frees them automatically).

Answer (score 1):

I see that there are lots of shots at trying to solve your problem by now, but I have a feeling that you're looking in the wrong end - why do you *actually* want to do this in the first place? Is there some interesting functionality in the base class that you have omitted to specify?

The fact that you'd be forced to switch on a property type id to do what you want with a specific instance is a code smell, *especially* when the subclasses have absolutely nothing in common via the base class other than a name (which is the type id in this case).

Answer (score -1):

You can probably do this with the Boost library, or you could create a class with a type code and a `void` pointer to the data, but it would mean giving up some of the type safety of C++.  In other words, if you have a property "foo", whose value is an integer, and give it a string value instead, the compiler will not find the error for you.

I would recommend revisiting your design, and re-evaluating whether or not you really need so much flexibility.  Do you really need to be able to handle properties of any type?  If you can narrow it down to just a few types, you may be able to come up with a solution using inheritance or templates, without having to "fight the language".