# List functionality c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, list, int

I have briefly looked around various c++ sites and text books. But none of them have had anything related to what I was looking for.

What I want is a list in c++ which can contain int, string and int array variables within it. But before I spend hours playing around with some code, I was wondering if anyone knew if such a thing actually exists? I'm not asking for code to be shown to me, if it is possible, I will attempt it, and then ask about any issues I have with it.

Thanks

Comment: You do know about the [C++ standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559412/how-to-store-different-data-types-in-one-list-c

Comment: So you want a container which can hold an objects of different types at the same time? Or a container which can hold objects of the same type for different types?

Comment: @StoryTeller I want a container which can hold objects of different types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html). Remember - I didn't tell you it will be easy.

Usage will be simple:

```
typedef boost::variant<...my necessary types...> MyVariant;

std::list<MyVariant> myList;
```

Comment: It may not be easy, but it will be gratifying.

Comment: @user3001499, consider accepting this answer if the proposed solution works for you.

Answer (score 2):

In case you meant an object that can contain int, string and arrays as **separate objects**, not as one (like union) -- I think you should take a look at [C++11 tuples](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/)
, and use them in list.

Comment: A list of tuples is not a list of object of different types... `std::tuple<int, std::string>`for example contains a int AND a string, not a int OR a string.

Comment: In a list, or instead of a list?

Comment: @Johan, yes it's AND, the question was stated about using int, string AND arrays. If the author of the question meant OR, than of course tuples are not the answer

Comment: @Apokal Can you clarify that in your answer so I remove my downvote ?

Comment: @Johan, thanks for you comments, now answer is more clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a struct using union or void pointer.

```
enum varType
{
    vt_int,
    vt_float,
    vt_string
}

class myVariant
{
private:
    void* mVariable;
    varType mType;
};
```

or also,

```
class myVariant2
{
private:
    union
    {
        float fValue;
        int iValue;
        std::string* sValue;        
    };
    varType mType;
}
```

It's not nice and would require casting heavily, but if you don't like using other libraries for such small task, this might be of help.

Edit1: You will need getStringValue, getFloatValue getIntValue functions.

Edit2: You can safely use this classes in std::list.

Edit3: You need to call destructor of std::string (if the variable is a string) yourself.

Comment: unions containing non-pod members are only available since c++11.

Comment: @StoryTeller: and they are non-trivial (you need to call the destructor yourself)

Comment: Then the union should include std::string* or even worse, char*. So I guess using void* is a better idea and is more flexible.

Comment: @revani, what!? no! This is the world of C++. There are far better alternatives. Take a look at boost::any or boost::variant.

Comment: @StoryTeller yeah, it's not nice at all and I wouldn't use in my own projects. But if the topic creator works for a big project which doesn't include boost or the project works in an embedded environment, this solution might be useful. I know boost isn't "very slow" but managers often tend to keep the output files as small as possible especially when working in embedded projects.

Comment: I used to work in a department that develops IP phones and boost was frowned upon. When a employee says "boost", the managers lose interest :D

Comment: @revani, this is why we can't have nice things :D

Answer (score 0):

It might be unsafe to put different types of objects/data in single list.

But if it the requirement, then why not derive new class from std::list with combination of keeping track of types being inserted into list using aproach mentioned in above answer.

Comment: I hesitate to downvote a newcomer, so please remove this answer and repeat after me: **Do not derive from STL containers! Do not derive from STL containers! Do not derive from STL container!**. The (long) justification is that: 1. You should favor composition over inheritance whenever feasible, 2. There is no (functional) benefit in inheriting from a class without `virtual` methods, 3. Inheriting from a class without a `virtual` destructor and with public copy/move constructors is a recipe for disaster (truncation).