# How to access data member of a template child class from a parent class in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am trying to store values of different types in one list. Now I am using @sbi's solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559412/how-to-store-different-data-types-in-one-list-c) post. So I have base class:

```
class Variable
{
    protected :
        std::string name;
    public :
        Variable ( std::string name ) : name( name ) { }
        virtual ~Variable () { }

        virtual Print() const = 0;
};
```

And class that derives from it

```
template<typename T>
class TypedVariable : public Variable
{
    protected :
        const T* value;

    public :
        TypedVariable ( TString name, const T* value )
        : Variable( name ),
          value( value ) { };

        T Value() { return *value; }

        void Print() const
        {
            std::cout << "name: " << name << "\n";
            std::cout << "value: " << *value << "\n";
        }
};
```

And then I store `Variable`s, for example in `std::array`

```
std::array<Variable*, size> myArray;
```

The problem is I cannot access `value` in this case because it is inside `TypedVariable` not `Variable`. My question is how do I access that field, if possible.

Comment: *"And class that derives from it"* - No, it doesn't.

Comment: Edited. Sorry, a typo.

Comment: if you know all possible types that can appear in your variable you could make use of type erasure and visitor pattern by utilizing `std::variant` or `boost::variant` for pre-c++17

Comment: @paraxod: The best way to ask a question is to create a file like `test.cpp`, put all your code in it, run it through a compiler to see if it gives the expected result, then copy and paste everything from your editor into the question. CTRL+V should be the only keystroke for the code in the browser window. No room for typos.

Comment: @ChristianHackl or even use some online version of compiler to share possible compilation errors :)

Comment: I suspect that I should use `std::variant` along with `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` wouldn't be necessary just use [`std::visit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) instead when you want to gain an access to the contained variable...

Comment: Use public field for you variable